# Make WebStorm ignore .spec.js files for "Choose Declaration" dropdown

Tags: javascript, jasmine, webstorm

WebStorm has a nice feature that lets you cmd-click on a function and go to its definition. Since I'm writing JavaScript (w/ AngularJS), those definitions aren't always precise, and it offers a list of choices.

The frustrating thing is when WebStorm deduces that the definition is actually in a test file, and brings me to a line where I'm declaring a mock object with the same name.

Is there a way to make WebStorm ignore certain files (e.g. `.spec.js` files) when looking for function definitions?

I've tried adding `*.spec.js` to the "Ignore files and folders" list in the Editor > File Types dialog. This does the trick, but then I can't access any `.spec.js` files from within Webstorm. They're all hidden, and I can't even create new files matching that pattern.

The test files are scattered around, mostly living next to the components they test, so I can't simply exclude the `tests` directory, for example.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: There is no option to ignore some stuff in specific popups/navigate to dialogs. What I may suggest to try: 1) right click and mark it as plain text -- now this file will be treated as plain text (not indexed as JS any more) 2) more radical -- assign such `*.spec.js` pattern to "Text files" File Type -- will do that globally (all projects).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's not possible. You can vote for a [similar feature](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127753)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with a concatenated .js file.
I solved it for me by "Marking the file as Plain Text"
In the "Project"-Pane --> right click on a js-file --> click "**Mark as Plain Text**"